# how to return the largest number from each sub array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I return the largest numbers from each sub array of a multidimension array? the output will be an array of largest numbers.

For example
array = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

returning value [ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]

I tried like

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    large = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] > large) {
        large = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.push(large);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

the output is only largest of first sub array (5)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: I am tempted to write `array.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null))` as answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye it works perfectly! Put it as answer, I upvote you: http://jsfiddle.net/3qf9qxu2/

Comment: @thefourtheye: That's just awful. Beautiful. Awful. Beautiful. Aaaaah!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know :D If OP had made some effort I would have added that also in the answer and explained it :(

Comment: @thefourtheye You can add the answer anyway

Comment: Please check this out and then restructure your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be also better to transfer this question to Community wiki

Comment: @hindmost I have tried this  function largestOfFour(arr) {
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    large = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] > large) {
        large = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.push(large);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

Comment: @thefourtheye thank you. but it can done by using for loop and if statement?

Answer (score 2):

I have been through the code and ended with a final solution. The first for loop iterates through the big array and the second one through the components of the subarray. The if checks for the biggest number.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var main = [];
  for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
     var long=0;
       for(i=0;i<arr[k].length;i++){
          if(long<arr[k][i]) {
              long=arr[k][i];
          }
       }
   main.push(long);
   }
  return main;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have got answer to my question

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var largest = 0;
    for (j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > largest) {
        largest = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    newArr.push(largest);
  }
  // You can do this!
  return newArr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a simple loop, you need to create a return array and push the results there. In your code you have pushed an item only at the end (`return arr.push(large)`).

Hope it's clear

Regards,

Dan