# Creating an array consisting of the largest values of each sub-array does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Find the largest number in each of the sub-array and then make an array of those largest numbers.`[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]`

I wrote some code, and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Maybe the Array.push() method doesn't work or perhaps the for loops.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var main = [];
    for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
       var long= 0;
         for(i=0;i<arr[k].length;i++){
            if(arr[k][i]<long) {
                arr[k][i] = long;
            }
            main.push[long];
        }
    }
    return main
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]], "");
```

Comment: you need to reset `long` for each k loop ... i.e. move var long=0 to the top of the for k loop

Comment: Please do not correct the code in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is on the inner loop, when you try to find the max value for each array. On each iteration of the outer loop, you should reset `long = arr[k][0]`. It should not be reset to 0 since the max value may be smaller than 0. Note that this expects all subarrays to have at least one item.

As noted by @edc65, the declaration of `long` should occur at the start of the function to make it clear that `long`, as all local variables, has a function scope.

---

You only want one value per subarray. Therefore you should be adding one value for each iteration of the outer loop (`main.push` should be in the outer loop). The way it is currently, you are adding one value per subarray element.

---

In the if statement, your assignment is inverted. It should be

```
long = arr[k][i];
```

And the condition is also inverted. `long` stores the max value for each subarray. Therefore, you update it if you find a value **greater** than it:

```
if(arr[k][i]>long) {
    long = arr[k][i];
}
```

---

When pushing into the array use parenthesis, not brackets:

```
main.push(long);
```

Parenthesis are for calling methods. Brackets are for accessing properties in an object.

### Final code

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var main = [];
    var long;
    for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
       long = arr[k][0];
         for(i=0;i<arr[k].length;i++){
            if(arr[k][i]>long) {
                long = arr[k][i];
            }
        }
        main.push(long);
    }
    return main;
}
```

---

### [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method

You can use `Math.max` to simplify your code

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var main = [];
    for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
        var long = Math.max.apply(null, arr[k]);
        main.push(long);
    }
    return main;
}
```

As per [@BillyMoon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679349/5119090) and [@Tushar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/5119090) answers, this can be further simplified to an [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) call.

Comment: I'd go with `long = arr[k][0]` instead of `long = 0` when you reset it. This will handle the case where the numbers are all negative.

Comment: having var long... inside the for is a (minor) problem too. All the local variables are at function scope and should be declared at top. Instead it seems that long in scoped inside to for(), that is not

Answer (score 6):

I know the question here is to find a bug in the existing code, in case if you may want to optimise the code

The original [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936187/how-to-return-the-largest-number-from-each-sub-array-using-javascript#comment51783530_31936187) is of [@thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye). I'm just explaining this here.

No need of nested loops, you can achieve this in *single line*.

```js
var arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

var result = arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null));

document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

How this works?

The array.map function is iterating over each of the elements from array on which it is called.
The function passed to the `map` here is `apply` with its `this` context bound to the `Math.max` and first argument bound to `null`.

`Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null)` this basically calls the `Math.max` function on array as

```
Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

**Update:**

With ES6, [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), this can be made even smaller

```
arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))
```

```js
var arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

var result = arr.map(e => Math.max(...e));

document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Potentially simpler method to achieve same result - simplicity is prerequisite for reliability...

```
function largestOfFour(arr){
    // assumes compatible browser, or shim: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility
    // map array each element into new value based on callback's return
    return arr.map(function(subarr){
        // sort to get highest value at front, and then return it
        return subarr.sort(function(a,b){
            return b-a;
        })[0];
    });
}
```

---

**or with Math.max (see comments...)**

```
function largestOfFour(arr){
    // assumes compatible browser, or shim: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility
    // map array each element into new value based on callback's return
    return arr.map(function(subarr){
        // sort to get highest value at front, and then return it
        return Math.max.apply(null, subarr);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use `Math.max` instead of sorting the array (both for efficiency and immutability reasons)

Answer (score 0):

I have been through the code and ended with other solution. The first for loop iterates through the big array and the second one through the components of the subarray.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var main = [];
  for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
     var long=0;
       for(i=0;i<arr[k].length;i++){
          if(long<arr[k][i]) {
              long=arr[k][i];
          }
       }
   main.push(long);
   }
  return main;
}
```