# JavaScript - Return value from array with map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract the largest number of every single array. I believe it should be possible with the .map function.

This is what I have so far, but unfortunately this returns " [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]"

Code:

```
function largestOfFour(largestOfFour) {
    largestOfFour.forEach(function(number){
        number.sort(function(a, b){
            return b - a;
        });
        highestValue = number.map(function(number){
            return number[0];
        });
    });
};

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have `number` as the parameter to your `forEach` and then `number` again in your `map` function. So inside your `map` function, what do you think `number` refers to (hint, it isn't an array).

Comment: Use `arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null));` Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/2025923) for explanation and demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the outer array,

```
function largestOfFour(largestOfFour) {
    largestOfFour.forEach(function(number){
```

and then sorting the inner arrays,

```
number.sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
});
```

and then of those inner arrays you're trying to acquire the `[0]` property from each value, which is `undefined`

```
highestValue = number.map(function(number){
// you redefine `number` here to be the value within the inner array
    return number[0];
});
```

What you probably want to do is `map` the *outer* array:

```
function largestOfFour(largestOfFour) {
    largestOfFour.map(function(numbers){
```

sort the inner arrays:

```
numbers.sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
});
```

and then return the first value:

```
return numbers[0];
```

---

All together it probably should be:

```
function largestOfFour(largestOfFour) {
    return largestOfFour.map(function(numbers){
        numbers.sort(function(a, b){
            return b - a;
        });
        return numbers[0];
    });
}
```

Although there are simpler ways to find the maximum values of an array of arrays.

One such example is to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function largestValues(outer) {
    return outer.map(function (inner) {
        return inner.reduce(function (prev, current) {
            return Math.max(prev, current);
        }, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, very good explanation on why it wasn't working too!

Answer (score 2):

There's a shorter way of finding the largest number in each array using `Math.max`:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function (el) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, el);
  });
}; // [ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4LLu4ot/)

Comment: There's _even_ shorter way. Use `arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null));` Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/2025923) for explanation and demo

Comment: @Tushar, [short, clever code is not better than more verbose simple code](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/debugging-clever-code).

Comment: @zzzzBov True. But once you understand the syntax(or with comments), it's good and concise code.

Comment: @Andy I know about the Math method, but I don't understand what " apply.bind"  does. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You should ask @Tushar

Comment: @Cake Check my first comment and read the description

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y48qz6hx/
Just fixed your code

```
function largestOfFour(largestOfFour) {
    largestOfFour.forEach(function(number, index){
        number.sort(function(a, b){
            return b - a;
        });
        largestOfFour[index] = number[0];
    });

    alert(largestOfFour);
};

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var ar=[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

   console.log( ar.map(x=> Math.max.apply(null, x)) )
```

Comment: I've got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>`

Comment: The function name is "largestOfFour". Not the first element of the array.

Comment: @AlexanderElgin, that's because this answer is in ES6 and probably no help to you.

Comment: @Andy the OP asks: 'I want to extract the first number of every single array...' (not the largest like in function name )

Comment: Then why is the function name "largestOfFour" and the code sorting each array? The OP probably meant to write the first element of a sorted array.

Comment: @Andy I corrected it to find the largest

Comment: @AlexanderElgin arrow function should be supported on  all updated browsers, what are you using?

Comment: maybe not  http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions