# largest no in array (js program)

Tags: javascript

Return Largest Numbers in Arrays

```
//my code
function largestOfFour(arr) {

    var largest=[];    

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] > largest){
                largest[i]= arr[i][j];

            }


        }

    }
   return largest;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

//exp o/p

```
[27,5,39,1001]
```

//i m getting

```
[5,13]
```

Comment: Expected output should be `[5, 27, 39, 1001]`.

Comment: [`arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/2025923)

Comment: i m getting [5, 13 ] only on the freecodecamp editor

Comment: Try `arr[0].map(e => Math.max(...e))` as your array is array of arrays and not separate params.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arr[i][j]>largest)
```

should be

```
if(arr[i][j]>largest[i])
```

Initialize your array too with some MIN value like 0

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

var largest=[];    

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
    largest[i] = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if(arr[i][j] > largest[i]){
            largest[i]= arr[i][j];

        }


    }

}
  return largest;
}
```

Comment: i m getting aans as [5,0,0,0]

Comment: i forgot editing largest[i] in comparison , try updated

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way.

```js
var largest=[];    

a = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ 
largest.push(a[i].sort(function(a, b){return b-a})[0])
}
console.log(largest);
```